# nixos: derivation pulling from github, leaving .git

Tags: github, nix, nixos

I'm trying to build a derivation (for [keyboardio](http://keyboard.io/) firmware) that pulls from github, but leaves the `.git` directory in place (because the make system looks for it).

I have tried the `fetchFromGitHub` function in the expression, but `leaveDotGit` falls through to `fetchzip` which then complains that it doesn't know how to handle it.

I have tried to use the `nix-prefetch-github` executable with `--leave-dotGit`, but although that works fine on the cmdline, it blows up when called as part of a `builder.sh` with the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nix/store/3jqkkq639rs8yi9rrl1cg9j5ii0kx3x7-nix-prefetch-github-1.3/bin/.nix-prefetch-github-wrapped", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/nix/store/7v2xsnl1svflfqm73hnbbmhmm4mvwi0s-python3.6-click-6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/nix/store/7v2xsnl1svflfqm73hnbbmhmm4mvwi0s-python3.6-click-6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 676, in main
    _verify_python3_env()
  File "/nix/store/7v2xsnl1svflfqm73hnbbmhmm4mvwi0s-python3.6-click-6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/_unicodefun.py", line 118, in _verify_python3_env
    'for mitigation steps.' + extra)
RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment.  Consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/for mitigation steps.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/nix/store/3jqkkq639rs8yi9rrl1cg9j5ii0kx3x7-nix-prefetch-github-1.3/bin/.nix-prefetch-github-wrapped", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/nix/store/7v2xsnl1svflfqm73hnbbmhmm4mvwi0s-python3.6-click-6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/nix/store/7v2xsnl1svflfqm73hnbbmhmm4mvwi0s-python3.6-click-6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 676, in main
    _verify_python3_env()
  File "/nix/store/7v2xsnl1svflfqm73hnbbmhmm4mvwi0s-python3.6-click-6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/_unicodefun.py", line 118, in _verify_python3_env
    'for mitigation steps.' + extra)
RuntimeError: Click will abort further execution because Python 3 was configured to use ASCII as encoding for the environment.  Consult http://click.pocoo.org/python3/for mitigation steps.
```

How do I go about achieving this?

Thanks,

Comment: It's generally better to avoid leaving .git, because its contents are not deterministic. You may be able to patch the git build dependency and/or insert the commit sha via your Nix expressions.

Comment: Yeah, I'll buy that.  But patching the dependency is non-trivial, and inserting the commit sha doesn't help me keep the .git (or does it?).

Comment: Correct. Did you try `fetchGit`?

Comment: Actually, I didn't (foolishly thought fetchFromGitHub was the thing for ... fetching from github :-) ).  Thanks for the pointer.  But I can't see how to convince fetchGit to get submodules, too.

Comment: The built-in variation doesn't seem to support it, but the one in Nixpkgs should. https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/fetchgit/default.nix#L16

Comment: Ah yes, now I see the distinction between fetchgit & fetchGit.  That did it!  Many thanks for your patient assistance.